# Visual Studio Long Build Time on Form Modification

Tags: c#, forms, build

I am currently working on a C# Forms Application.

I noticed that every time I make changes to a form in the designer, it takes a long time to build the application.

I tried to modify code in the class itself, and this does not slow down the build.

Does anyone know what might be causing this, as its getting very irritating?

Thanks,

PM

Comment: Do you have a lot of controls on the form?

Comment: Are you using a lot of bitmaps in your controls or forms?

Comment: Yes, but the bitmaps are only loaded at runtime from the resources.

Comment: JP found your problem - resx files take a while to compile depending on the size of the resources. You could try ship the raw files in your application directory.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct solution, I had success investigating similar issues using Sysinternal's [Process  Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653) to see which resources (files, registry, etc.) a process is accessing.

Maybe you can use this (free) tool to get a clue on what devenv.exe (or csc.exe or similar tools) is accessing.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to go to:

```
"Tools " ---> "Options" ---> "Windows Forms Designer" ---> "Toolbox" node
```

and check the value under "AutoToolboxPopulate". I have had huge performance issues when the value is set to "True". Changing this to "False" will help, but make sure you close the solution and open it again (I would even close Visual Studio IDE and relaunch it).